# Windows 7: Enable touchscreen features for non-touchscreen PCs

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

Is there a way to hack Windows 7 into thinking that my PC has touchscreen? I am not talking about enabling the on-screen keyboard (OSK), or the Table Input Panel to "simulate" touchscreen. Nor do I want to use simulators similar to what Visual Studio offers.

Essentially, I want my mouse to behave as though it is a stylus or a finger (I realize that multi-touch won't work). For example, I want the keyboard icon to appear when the Google search box is in focus.

Thank you.

Comment: http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/?